# How to connect to a Firebird database from Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, firebird, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and I'm trying to read data from Firebird database.

I installed the package via Composer: [laravel-firebird](https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird)

I created a 'config' folder with a database.php file as in Laravel and defined my connection to Firebird and register in app.php

$app->configure('database');

I created my Model and a Controller to read the data. However, the error is returning:

**Unsupported driver [firebird]**

What should I do?
Do I need to register the Provider? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following line in the **Services Providers** part of the **app.php** file:

```
$ app-> register (\ Firebird \ FirebirdServiceProvider :: class);
```